# How to share a scoped variable between directive and view page?

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm attempting to load a spinner while a get request accessing data and then display message 'Get Request completed' once get request completes.

This is how I'm attempting to toggle the display :

```
    <span ng-show="!isFinishedLoading">
    <img src="http://www.broadwaybalancesamerica.com/images/ajax-loader.gif">
    </span> 

    <span ng-show="isFinishedLoading">
   Get Request completed
    </span>
```

But the  variable `isFinishedLoading` is not on the scope.

How to toggle the between spinner and request depending on scoped variable ?

plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/F0XsOPZKq5HArFo9vtFs?p=preview

src :

```
2. http-hello2.html

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl">

<label>Filter: <input ng-model="search"></label> 

<div ng-repeat="sourceUrl in sourceUrls | filter:search track by $index ">

  <status-viewer  url="sourceUrl">   </status-viewer>


    <span ng-show="!isFinishedLoading">
    <img src="http://www.broadwaybalancesamerica.com/images/ajax-loader.gif">
    </span> 

    <span ng-show="isFinishedLoading">
   Get Request completed
    </span> 

    </div>



</div>


  </body>
</html>


<!--<h1>{{url}}</h1>-->
<div>
    <p>{{model}}</p> 

</div>

var myapp = angular.module('app', []).controller('FetchCtrl', FetchCtrl)

myapp.directive('statusViewer', function ($http , $interval) {
            return { 
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html', 
                scope: {
                    url: '='
                },  
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

                    console.log('invoked')


                    scope.isFinishedLoading = false;

                    $http.get(scope.url).success(function (data) {
                         scope.model = data;
                         scope.isFinishedLoading = true;
                    });
                }
            };
        });

function FetchCtrl($scope, $http, $q , $parse) {


$scope.sourceUrls = [
                'http-hello2.html'
            ,'http-hello2.html'];



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expose a scope which in the directive, here's the working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jcKGOPEjIxQkUSUVdBOI?p=preview)

expose the scope like:

```
scope: {
   url: '=',
   isFinishedLoading: '='
},
```

so the template would look like:

```
<status-viewer  url="sourceUrl" is-finished-loading='isFinishedLoading'>   </status-viewer>

<span ng-show="!isFinishedLoading">
<img src="http://www.broadwaybalancesamerica.com/images/ajax-loader.gif">
</span> 

<span ng-show="isFinishedLoading">
   Get Request completed
</span> 

</div>
```

so your `FetchCtrl`s `isFinishedLoading` is now two way bounded inside your `status-viewer`s scope.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RIuaOwI1FE008zpi4QQn?p=preview)

You need to share variables through the directive scope. You could also show the spinner inside the directive, would make things easier, if you don't need them outside.

```
  scope: {
     url: '=',
     model: '='
  },
```

If you put additional properties on that model, they will be visible from where you called the controller.